# How do I get my chrome extension to inject its iFrame adjacent to, rather than on top of the existing page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a `Chrome Extension` that injects itself into an `iFrame` that is appended to the `BODY` of the host page. However this `iFrame` appears above the existing page content, not adjacent to it.

I've tried appending the `iFrame` directly to the `HTML` element instead of the `BODY` but that doesn't appear to make any difference.

How do I inject it such that the `iFrame` pushes the host page content over, so all of that content is still accessible by the user?

Comment: do you check the z-index of the item you inserted, and the z-index of the original page?

Comment: What is the `position` CSS style of the iframe?

Comment: Thanks for the comments but the issue is not with the placement, but with the fact that I wish to force the host page to adjust its width to make room for the `iFrame`. Simply pushing my `iFrame` below the host page by changing the z-index is not what I am after. The `iFrame` is positioned correctly, but overlaps the host page rather than being injected adjacent to it.